Locating a hornet nest
Say you are noticing relatively many hornets since 2 weeks or so, showing up at the windows of a flat you are living in.
The frequency of hornets constantly probing the windows is relatively high. That means if you open a small window for just 5 minutes there is a high probably that up to 5 hornets get in. Even when just tilting the windows open by a few centimeters, the probability is relatively high that a hornet that probes the area enters the room in the next 2 minutes.
The suspicion that there is a hornet nest not too far away perhaps isn't too far fetched. But I'm not an entomologist.
Thus my question: How to locate the nest of those hornets, in such a scenario?
Are there some specific hornet traits that help to include/exclude certain areas/locations?
For example, perhaps it's well known (to experts) in what radius around their nest hornets are most actively searching for food.
Perhaps hornets prefer to keep searching in a certain height difference relative to their nest.
Or there might be other clues, such as birds avoiding a certain tree where the nest is located, debris/damages near/below the nest etc.

Some more details of this scenario:

this is in Germany, Europe
the hornets are either European (Vespa crabro) or Asian (Vespa velutina) ones
apparently there were some sightings of Asian hornets last year, in the next town
some of the hornets entering the room are very attracted to black installations at the ceiling
even when windows are closed and light curtains are drawn behind the window hornets are probing the windows and often flying against the shut window
one affected flat is at the 2nd floor (counting from zero), but hornets are also probing windows at other flats at the 3rd and 4th floors.


Is this rural or urban - are there garden areas, what sort (trees?)? Are therefood sources nearby - bird feeders (sugar water) or lots of exposed wood (used for making nests)?

@bob1 it's urban. On several sides of the building there are relatively large trees standing very near to the house. The house has 8 floors and there are 4 flats on each floor, and each flat has a balcony. Around the house there are a few meters of small garden areas and a green drive-way for fire-fighter access. Behind the house a larger park-like green area is starting, i.e. there are layers of bushes and trees there as well, a line of garages behind the bushes etc. It seems there are quite a few candidates for a nest location, e.g. some niche at some balcony, in a tree, a bush, etc.

One way would be to place some suitable food outside and try to follow the flight. Unfortunately my experience with hornets/wasps is they can travel several hundred metres if they need to, but the numbers you are seeing indicate a nest might be nearby.

@bob1 Ok, interesting idea. Btw, I didn't notice such bird feeders in the area, although some people provide small corn-bags or similar for birds. Besides the wood available in the trees/bushes and some exposed wood in nearby gardens, the windows have wooden bars, which were originally painted, of course, but not all are in good shape.

Note that in Germany hornets are a protected species (at least the European variety, not sure about the Asian one). You are not supposed to kill even individual ones, much less try to harm or destroy their nest. If you want to get rid of them, the recommended way is to contact the Naturschutzbehörde responsible for your town.

@quarague Of course. I'm confident that's possible to locate a hornet nest without harming the hornets. When a hornet nest is located one can hire a licensed professional who is qualified to identify the exact species with some confidence. Vespa crabro indeed is protected by German law. However, it's still possible for a professional to get a permit to carefully move a nest, under some circumstances, apparently. Vespa velutina actually is considered an invasive specifies and thus isn't protected. In fact, it must be reported to the authorities, per EU regulation, for pest control purposes.
